# error trying to host rest c# api on IIS 10.0

Tags: c#, .net, iis, asp.net-web-api

I am running on a remote server with Windows Server Datacenter 2016, IIS Ver 10. The windows features for asp.net are turned on. I compiled the restful c# API with Visual Studio 2022 and the generated web.config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\sifuentes-rest-api-net.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>           
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 196A5643-6588-45B1-8A25-A4ED46135EF7-->
```

I get error code `0x8007000d` which after reading around the net should mean that there is an error in there. I read one that suggested removing the `V@` in the module but I get the same error.

I published to a folder and copied and pasted the published folder from my local to the corresponding folder in the remote server. I am not certain what it could be? I have seen port related rules, versions of the frameworks installed and nothing seems to solve it.

Comment: download and install dotnet core hosting bundle Base on your sdk version . https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet

Comment: You can easily miss quite a few settings, so better run a report to learn more, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: I client does not have any access to the IIS server resources like filesystem.  A client only has GUEST privilege on IIS server.  It is not recommended to give service ADMIN rights.  So if you are using any files on server you should put them on a Network Drive where uses can be given access to the files.

Comment: Do you have any other error messages besides the 0x8007000d error code? usually IIS  Error 0x8007000d says about invalid element in your web.config, that's why iis cannnot read this file for start your site. You can find probloem element by commenting some blocks and looking for type of error.